Movie about kids digging holes all over the day
I searching for a movie about some Kids in summer camp that had to dig all the day I think because the camp owners are looking for gold so they exploit kids.
The movie is mostly american and I think it's produced in the 80 years 
Sorry if I gave so little informations It's all I can remember 

The 2003 Disney movie called... Holes. As you described, a bunch of kids are forced to dig holes at a juvenile detention camp (instead of being sent to a prison for minors) that's at a dried up lake bed. To "build character", they are forced to dig holes, but really are just being used to find a lost treasure. 

beat me by 54s because imdb is down, doh!

"If you take a bad boy and make him dig a hole every day in the hot sun, it will turn him into a good boy. "

Probably Holes (2003) 

Stanley Yelnats IV is a teenager born to a family who have been cursed
  with bad luck. His father is an inventor who has been trying to find a
  solution to the problem of foot odor for years, without success. One
  day, Stanley is falsely accused of stealing a pair of sneakers donated
  to a homeless shelter by a celebrity athlete and is convicted. He
  decides to attend Camp Green Lake, a juvenile detention camp, in lieu
  of serving a jail sentence, under the assumption he is going to a
  summer camp instead of a boot camp. 
He arrives to find that the camp
  is a dried-up lake run by the Warden, Louise Walker, her assistant Mr.
  Sir, and camp counselor Dr. Pendanski. Prisoners spend each day
  digging holes in the desert to "build character." The inmates are told
  that they may earn a day off, if they find anything interesting or
  unusual. After finding a golden tube initialed K.B. and a fossil,
  Stanley is accepted into the group and is given the nickname
  "Caveman." After taking responsibility for Magnet's stealing of Mr.
  Sir's sunflower seeds, Stanley is taken to the warden's house where
  old wanted posters and newspapers lead him to suspect that "K.B."
  stands for Kate Barlow. 
In a series of flashbacks the history of Camp
  Green Lake is revealed. It is originally a lake town, thriving with
  water and life until Katherine Barlow, a local teacher, falls in love
  with an African American onion seller named Sam. Sam helps rebuild
  Kate's schoolhouse and becomes closer to her. One day she kisses Sam
  despite the town's segregation laws. "Trout" Walker, the wealthiest
  man in town, who had unsuccessfully pursued Kate, sees them kissing. A
  group of men led by Walker burn the schoolhouse, along with Sam's
  onion stand, and kill his donkey Mary Lou. In desperation, Kate seeks
  the help of the local sheriff, who is drunk in preparation for the
  hanging of Sam for his crime. He demands a kiss, but she refuses.
  After witnessing the death of Sam at the hands of Walker and the
  posse, Kate kills the sheriff in retaliation and then kisses his
  forehead, leaving a lipstick imprint. She becomes known as "Kissin'
  Kate" Barlow, an outlaw who robs banks and stagecoaches. Sam's death
  causes the Green Lake to turn into an arid wasteland, implied to be
  divine punishment, which leads to the desertion of the town and
  financial ruin of Walker and his family. Years later, the now bankrupt
  Walkers corners Kate on the dry lake bed and demands she hand over her
  buried treasure, but Kate responds that they could "dig for a hundred
  years" and not find it. She tells Walker to "start digging," then
  grabs a highly venomous yellow-spotted lizard with her bare hands and
  lets it bite her, causing her to die within minutes. For over a
  century, the Walker family dig for the treasure, finding nothing.
While digging one day, Pendanski mocks Zero, who responds by hitting
  Pendanski with a shovel and running into the desert. Stanley pursues
  and carries Zero up a mountain called "God's Thumb", where they find a
  wild field of radishes and a spring, helping them regain strength and
  at the same time unknowingly fulfilling his ancestor's vow to the
  fortune teller Madame Zeroni (who is Zero's ancestor), to carry a
  member of the Zeroni family up the mountain and allow them to drink
  from the stream while singing to them, thus breaking the curse, and
  restoring his family's luck. His father suddenly discovers that a
  mixture of peaches and onions removes foot odor. 
Stanley and Zero
  decide to return to the camp and investigate the hole where Stanley
  found the lipstick. Digging deeper, they uncover a chest, but are
  immediately discovered by Walker and Mr. Sir. But the hole is suddenly
  filled with yellow-spotted lizards and the boys have to remain still.
  Texas officials and Stanley's lawyer arrive, and the warden accuses
  Stanley of stealing the chest from her cabin. Zero points out that the
  chest has Stanley's name on it. The boys climb out of the hole without
  upsetting the lizards. It is revealed that the warden is Trout's
  granddaughter and for years she has used the inmates to search for the
  treasure. The warden, Mr. Sir (who is revealed to be a paroled
  criminal named Marion Seville), and Pendanski (who is impersonating a
  doctor) are arrested. Stanley and Zero (whose file was destroyed when
  the warden was trying to cover up his presumed death in the desert)
  are released from the now-under-investigation camp. With justice
  finally being served for Sam, rain returns to Green Lake for the first
  time in over 100 years. The Yelnats family claims ownership of the
  chest which contains jewels, old money, deeds and promissory notes
  which they evenly share with Zero. Zero reunites with his missing
  mother, Camp Green Lake is closed and the Yelnats and the Zeronis move
  to new neighboring houses along with their friends.

